# I want to have a formatted date 5 days in the past

Tags: powershell, formatting

So in my Powershell script I am writing I need to code in a date that is 5 days in the past. I have this but I know it wont work with my formatting method I am using. I just need to figure out how to format it and make it 5 days prior for automation.

```
$StartTime = (Get-date).AddDays(-5)
$EndTime = Get-date -format "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ"
```

The end time has the formatting I want. But I cant apply the formatting to the start time after I perform the AddDays operation.

Thanks for any help. I've been racking my brain over this and I am sure I am just missing something simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$StartTime = (get-date).AddDays(-5).ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ")
```